# Can I say "I want to know how the data is corrected"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

What I want to say is "I want to know how the data is corrected", but I don't know if this is a correct sentence. Any problem on "how the data is corrected" part?

Comment: Absolutely, your grammar here is perfect.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. Do you want to know how the data have|has been corrected? Or how it|they is|are to be corrected?  That is, what has been fixed, or what needs to be fixed?

Comment: What is the differences between "how the data has been corrected" and "how it is to be corrected"?

Comment: First (has been): was already fixed.  Second (is to be): Not fixed yet. It is not clear which you mean to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a common thing to 'correct' data, as data normally just refers to raw results obtained from experiment or observation or whatever.

But, regardless of semantics, it's a perfectly logical and grammatically correct (and various other big words) description.

Comment: How about fix the data?